# Start on shell file crash

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, unity

I am REALLY bad at shell scripting.  How do I make a script that launches

```
~/start.sh unturnedrp
```

And makes sure that it is running, and if it isn't, run it again.  Even if it crashes with a **sigsev**.  The reason I need this is because my game server needs to be shut down every couple hours, and sometimes it crashes because of an overload of items.

EDIT:  Here is the code for start.sh

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# This script starts a Unturned 3 server on Linux machines

# To start servers with this script, place it next to Unturned.exe

# Syntax: start.sh <instance name>

# Author: fr34kyn01535


export MONO_IOMAP=all


#CONFIG

INSTANCE_NAME=$1

STEAMCMD_HOME="$PWD/../steamcmd"

UNTURNED_HOME="$PWD"


#COLORS

RED='\033[0;31m'

GREEN='\033[0;32m'

YELLLOW='\033[0;33m'

NC='\033[0m'


#Steam checks

STEAMCMD_API=$STEAMCMD_HOME/linux32/steamclient.so

UNTURNED_API=$UNTURNED_HOME/Unturned_Data/Plugins/x86/steamclient.so

printf "Steam: "

if [ -f $STEAMCMD_API ]; then

    if diff $STEAMCMD_API $UNTURNED_API >/dev/null ; then

        printf "${GREEN}UP TO DATE${NC}\n\n"

    else

        cp $STEAMCMD_API $UNTURNED_API

        printf "${YELLLOW}UPDATING${NC}\n\n"

    fi

else

    printf "${RED}NOT FOUND${NC}\n\n"

fi


cd $UNTURNED_HOME


if [ -f RocketLauncher.exe ]; then

    ulimit -n 2048

    mono RocketLauncher.exe $INSTANCE_NAME

else

    echo "RocketLauncher not found."

fi
```

Edit: also it would be nice to check if unturned_api is greater than steamcmd_api and if it is then cp unturned_api and once that is done, restart the server

Comment: What did you try so far? Please add your attempt to your question.

Comment: Any particular reason you're looking for a shell script instead of creating a systemd service?

Comment: It opens up another prompt that I can type commands into

Comment: What is a systemd service?  I am not a linux superhero as I only have linux for my gaem server.  Thanks

Comment: *"It opens up another prompt that I can type commands into"* There's a few things you might mean by that. The server software might have its own interactive prompt, different from the shell prompt you used to run it. Or it might run in the background and immediately return you to your shell. Or it might create a (separate) graphical window with a new prompt of some kind inside. Can you run the command, then copy all text from the terminal, **[edit]** your question to paste it in, then select what you pasted and press Ctrl+K (or click **{}**) to format it? Please also mention what game this is.

Comment: Ok i edited it and added the code